# objectify filter with ancestor not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Objectify filter with ancestor is not working, check below code:

```
List<AccountGroupEntity> list = ofy().load()
                .type(AccountGroupEntity.class)
                .ancestor(Key.create(BusinessEntity.class, bid)).filter("accountGroupType=", type)
                .list();
```

Comment: Does Key.create(BusinessEntity.class, bid) returns something? What happens if you don't filter on AccountGroupType?

Comment: List<AccountGroupEntity> list = ofy().load()
    .type(AccountGroupEntity.class)
    .ancestor(Key.create(BusinessEntity.class, bid)).filter("accountGroupType", type)
    .list();

Comment: I am not sure to understand your answer. I was trying to give debug directions by asking 1/ if you have check that you correctly get the ancestor entity with Key.create(BusinessEntity.class, bid) and 2/ what happens if you don't filter, i.e. List<AccountGroupEntity> list = ofy().load() .type(AccountGroupEntity.class) .ancestor(Key.create(BusinessEntity.class, bid)).list();

Comment: @deepalimate Welcome to SO! Please take the time to go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, in particular check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a terrible question - you should explain what you mean by "it doesn't work" - the problem is almost certainly that you are filtering by the exact literal value "accountGroupType=". You need a space before the '='.